# Hibernate. Give a value to all fields in a column that have a value of null

Tags: java, hibernate

```
    try(Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
        session.beginTransaction();
        String hql = "update EmployeeTask set employee = 1 where employee is null";
        session.createQuery(hql, EmployeeTask.class).executeUpdate();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

throws the following

Caused by: org.hibernate.query.IllegalQueryOperationException: Result type given for a non-SELECT Query [update EmployeeTask set employee = 1 where employee is null]

I expect that all values of the "employee" column that are currently null will have the value 1

Comment: Is the `employee` field in your `EmployeeTask` an integer? Or is it an `Employee` object. You are writing an HQL hence you should use your object model, else write a SQL query. Also it is an Update it doesn't return a `EmployeeTask` but rather a `long`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line of code:

session.createQuery(hql, EmployeeTask.class).executeUpdate();

Hibernate is telling what is the problem:

Caused by: org.hibernate.query.IllegalQueryOperationException: **Result type given for a non-SELECT Query**

This is an update query, not a select query, so you don't need to give the result type. Therefore you must change the above line of code as shown below:

session.createQuery(hql).executeUpdate();

Answer (score 2):

`session.createQuery(hql, EmployeeTask.class)` is used to **retrieving** data from the database. You can use the `session.createQuery(hql)` methed for **update, or delete statement.**, but this method is **deprecated** and you may get problems in the future when you update Hibernate to a newer version.

Here is alternative methods:

- `session.createMutationQuery(hql)` -  to insert, update, or delete statement.
- `createNativeMutationQuery​(String sqlString)` - but this takes native SQL statement string

See [the javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/spi/QueryProducerImplementor.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

look to documents.
Execute an update or delete statement.
* @**return the number** of entities updated or deleted